# When using selenium for python - cannot find Chrome binary for chromedriver

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

When trying to use selenium I keep receiving the error 'UnknownError: cannot find Chrome binary'

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\neal_\OneDrive\Documents\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get("https://dblp.org/")
```

I've downloaded the chromedriver at this location and used cmd to see if it actually runs and it gives the response 'chromedriver was started successfully'

I'm not sure where I'm going wrong here. Any suggestions greatly appreciated, most of the common/popular threads I've already followed and not found any avail.
Or if anyone has a guide to setting up selenium for windows thats straightforward, it would be also appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I coded this on my laptop and it's work (you can try on yours and say me if it's work ?)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\...")
```

Answer (score 0):

> Install selenium webdriver On windows 10

https://mundrisoft.com/tech-bytes/install-selenium-webdriver-windows/